# Not able to pass data from a page using getStaticProps to a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a next.js project and I'm trying to pass data from "gymlist" page to "table" component.

this is the "gymlist" page where I have the getStaticProps function:

```
export default function Gyms({gyms}) {
   return (
       <Table gyms={gyms}/>
   )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/gyms`)
  const gyms = await res.json()
  console.log(gyms);
  if (!gyms) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }
  return {
    props: {
      gyms,
      // Will be passed to the page component as props
    },
  };
  
}
```

the console.log shows the list of the gyms that I have in the database correctly.

This is the table component where I get the error: gyms.map is not a function

```
export default function Table(props) {
   const [gyms, setGyms] = useState(props);

   return (
   {gyms?.map((gym, index) => (
      <p> {gym.name} </p>
   ))}
   );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you try to use `props.gyms` to your `useState` default value, you are passing an object (the props object: `{ gyms: [...] }`), instead of the gyms array.

It could be solved by passing `props.gyms` to `useState`: `useState(props.gyms)`, or simply using `props.gyms` directly in your component render: `{props.gyms.map(...)}`.

You don't need state, in this case.